# VBA Find a last row within a range?

Tags: excel, range, vba

I want to find a last row with data within a range. for example i want to find a last empty row in range("A15:A42"). it should not go beyond A42. Any help.

```
lRow = Range("C15:C42").End(xlDown).Row   ....it goes beyond C42..
```

**IMP Info copied from comments**

> yes ..i will have some other data from C43 ... –  user2703472 3 hours ago

Comment: Maybe it's already done but you have to check your data first, are you sure that no value is present under line 42 in your column C ?

Comment: Also check if you are referencing in the correct sheet? the result of the code you posted vary depending on which sheet is selected.

Comment: yes ..i will have some other data from C43 ...

Comment: Yes i tried with Activesheet.Range. but it goes beyond c42 and gives me a row nr like 1026

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are trying? I am assuming that `C15` has data.

```
Option Explicit

Sub sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim LRow As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        Set rng = .Range("C15:C42")

        LRow = .Range(Split(.Cells(, rng.Column).Address, "$")(1) & _
               (rng.Row + rng.Rows.Count)).End(xlUp).Row

        Debug.Print LRow
    End With
End Sub
```

**ScreenShot**:

[image]